# Issues in integrating selenium with c# or nunit with Jira

Tags: java, c#, selenium, nunit, jira

I am an experienced selenium developer with java but I am now working for a project developed in C# and probably we would like to switch to selenium with c#. Can anyone highlight pain areas if any in using selenium with c#. Like if there are any issues in using nunit or writing appium mobile tests or integration of nunit with Jira etc...

Comment: How did you integrate JIRA when you were working with Selenium  and JAVA?

Comment: Understand that this is opinion-based and is not on-topic of SO (mostly because this will not be properly answered because there is no good answers). See [ask]. I have voted to close this question.